Post Rest API to upload pdf or jpg file from Oracle 21c
I need to send some documents to my server from my Oracle application, for this reason I created an API on my server using php
The API tested by PostMan and I can upload any file type.
Now I need to integrate it with my Oracle App, but I never write Oracle code ever. I used ChatGPT and check some resources on google to integrate it with following code:
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE read_pdf_file(p_file_name IN VARCHAR2, p_blob OUT BLOB) AS
      l_bfile BFILE;
    BEGIN
      l_bfile := BFILENAME('PDF_DIR', p_file_name);
      DBMS_LOB.OPEN(l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
      DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(p_blob, TRUE);
      DBMS_LOB.LOADFROMFILE(p_blob, l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(l_bfile));
      DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(l_bfile);
    END read_pdf_file;

    /***************************************************

  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE send_FILE_to_api(p_url IN VARCHAR2, p_file_name IN VARCHAR2) IS
      l_blob BLOB;
      l_base64 CLOB;
      l_http_req UTL_HTTP.req;
      l_http_resp UTL_HTTP.resp;
      l_resp_text VARCHAR2(32767);
      l_boundary VARCHAR2(64) := '----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW';
      l_crlf VARCHAR2(2) := CHR(13) || CHR(10);
      l_body CLOB;
      l_buffer        VARCHAR2(32767);
      l_clob CLOB ;
      l_offset INTEGER := 1;
      l_chunk_size CONSTANT INTEGER := 32767;
      l_chunk VARCHAR2(32767);
      l_clob_len INTEGER;
      l_read_len INTEGER ; 
      l_fix_inc INTEGER := 4000 ;
      amount BINARY_INTEGER := 32760;
      l_buffersize  number := 32767;
      l_vc  varchar2(32767);
    BEGIN
       -- Read the PDF file into a BLOB
      read_pdf_file(p_file_name, l_blob);
      l_clob := clobfromblob(l_blob) ;
  
 
      -- Construct the HTTP request body
      DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(l_body, TRUE);
      DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(l_body, LENGTH('--' || l_boundary || l_crlf), '--' || l_boundary || l_crlf);
      DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(l_body, LENGTH('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="' ||      p_file_name || '"' || l_crlf), 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="' || p_file_name || '"' || l_crlf);
      DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(l_body, LENGTH('Content-Type: application/pdf' || l_crlf || l_crlf), 'Content-Type: application/pdf' || l_crlf || l_crlf);
  
      DBMS_LOB.APPEND(l_body, l_clob);
      DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(l_body, LENGTH(l_crlf || '--' || l_boundary || '--' || l_crlf), l_crlf || '--' || l_boundary || '--' || l_crlf);

      -- Make the HTTP request
  
  
      UTL_HTTP.set_wallet('file:C:\WALLET', 'Tensor123');
  
      UTL_HTTP.set_transfer_timeout(60);
      l_http_req := UTL_HTTP.begin_request(p_url, 'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');
  
      UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_req, 'Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' || l_boundary);
  
  
      UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_req, 'Content-Length', DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(l_body));
  
  
      l_clob_len := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(l_body);
  
  
      while (l_offset <= l_clob_len)
       loop
        l_vc := dbms_lob.substr(l_body, l_buffersize, l_offset);
    
        UTL_HTTP.write_text(l_http_req, SUBSTR(l_vc, l_offset, l_buffersize));
    
        l_offset := l_offset + l_buffersize;
      end loop;
  
  
      l_http_resp := UTL_HTTP.get_response(l_http_req);

      -- Read the response
      BEGIN
        LOOP
          UTL_HTTP.read_text(l_http_resp, l_resp_text);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_resp_text);
      
        END LOOP;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN UTL_HTTP.end_of_body THEN
          NULL;
      END;

      UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_http_resp);
    END send_FILE_to_api ;


Using above code I can upload text files but when I try to upload pdf file I did not get any respond
I need some help to improve the code and upload pdf, jpg file using REST API from my Oracle app

Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226162/upload-blob-files-using-pl-sql-http

We have native REST API support for your database, and file uploads would require zero lines of php and only a few lines of easy to read SQL/PLSQL. Search on 'ORDS' and 'file upload'

@thatjeffsmith The OP appears to be trying to send BLOB data from a local database via a HTTP request to a remote server. The OP doesn't need a REST API for the database.

they could flip that and have an api that retrieves the file when requested by the local server

Yes MT10, I need to send data from my Oracle app to the server as pdf file
